# reactjs - digital time picker insted of analog time picer

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I'm using [meterial-ui-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-datetimepicker) in order to represent calender and time picker.
My time picker looks like that:

**My analog time picker**

[image: My analog time picker]

And I want to display it in digital mode, like this:

**Digital time picker**

[image: Digital time picker]

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import DateTimePicker from 'libs/DateTimePicker';
import DatePickerDialog from 'material-ui/DatePicker/DatePickerDialog';
import TimePickerDialog from 'material-ui/TimePicker/TimePickerDialog';

class DatetimeFilter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DateTimePicker
        DatePicker={DatePickerDialog}
        TimePicker={TimePickerDialog}
        onChange={this.handleTimeChange}
        floatingLabelText={this.props.label}
        timeFormat={'24hr'}
      />);
  }
}
```

1. Does meterial-ui have a digital form of time picker ?
2. If not, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

1 No it doesn't.

2 I use [rc-time-picker](http://react-component.github.io/time-picker/)

Comment: Do you familiar with some other solutions? I'm looking for something more stylish

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for something prettier.
Any other recommendations ? Even not like the one that I've attached to the post.